# Effective Domain Convex Function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ and let $S(f):=\{x ∈R^n | f(x) < +∞\}$ (effective domain)

How can I prove that $S(f)$ is convex doesn't imply that $f$ is convex?

**Attempt**:
I'm thinking of showing that $S(f)$ can vary depending whether $f(x)$ is a proper or improper function?

Comment: Can you give an example where $S(f)\not = \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I'm assuming f(x) is always a real number or $\pm∞$ so, no?

Comment: You should mention that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$. Also please explain how $S(f)$ is a subset of $P(f)$, they have different dimensions...

Comment: You're right. My bad, edited. Ignore my assumptions; only assumed that $S(f)$ is a subset of $P(f)$ on $R^n$

Comment: Let $x,y\in S(f)$ then $f(x),f(y)<\infty$. If $f$ is convex then $f(tx+(1-t)y)<tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)<\infty$ but this means that $tx+(1-t)y\in S(f)$ so it is convex. I think something is wrong with your question.

Comment: What you're saying is that S(f) will **always** be a convex set?

Comment: If $f$ is convex, it seems so.

Comment: I'm sorry Yanko. My formulation of the question is wrong.
What I'm asking for is if the **converse** of my statement holds.
If $S(f)$ is convex does that always mean that function $f(x)$ is also convex? My intuition tells me it generally doesn't but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I edit your question. Please check and see if this formulation is better.

Comment: Yes it's better. Thank you.

Comment: The solution is not that hard now. If $f$ never get the value infinity then $S(f)=\mathbb{R}^n$ (which is convex). So just find a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is not convex.